# Why do I get an error after adding connection string to code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, compiler-errors, syntax-error, connection-string

The connection string which I have copied from Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2019 is

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\dev\C# .net\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Because there are some `""` in the string, the code is returning an error.

This is the code:

```
string connectionstring =
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\dev\C# .net\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Comment: Replace ``"`` by ``""`` for ``AttachDbFilename``:``AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\dev\C# .net\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf""``

Comment: Please format your question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plain strings escape double quotes with `\"`.

```
string plain = "Double quote (\").";
```

For verbatim strings escape double quotes with `""`.

```
string verbatim = @"Double quote ("").";
```

Note: it doesn't matter whether it is a connection string or not. From the C# perspective, this is just a string.

```
string connectionstring =
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\dev\C# .net\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\Aadi Paw Plethysmometer\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```